# Generic http result in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I was already involved in couple of MVC projects, and in almost all of them i saw similar logic on some actions.

We often return object like this:

```
public class HttpPrjNameResult<T> {
    public PrjNameStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public T data{ get; set; }
}
```

So i wonder :

1. is there any standart MVC feature for that?
2. If no - why?
3. Or may be i use wrong pattern to write code?

**UDPATE:**
I will update question little bit.
Let's say I'm creating web api, with method UpdateReports, which returns list of updated entity:

```
public HttpTestResult<List<Report>> UpdateReports(IEnumerable<Reports> reports){
    try{
        var res = SaveReports(reports);
        return new HttpTestResult<List<Report>>{
            Status = TestStatus.Success,
            Data = res
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.Error(e);
        return new HttpTestResult<Object>{
            Status = TestStatus.Error,
            Message = "Error while saving reports"
        }
    }
}
```

And i see such logic useful all over the project, i guess more in API style, not in pure mvc, but still.
The question is - am i doing something wrong so this is kinda reinvent wheel, and there is already built in features for that kind of logic

Comment: bit unclear as to what you're asking? What are you trying to return to where?

Comment: Need more code / context. What situations do you address with this class?

Comment: now you've confused it even more. is this webapi or mvc? your title / tag is mvc, then you say `Let's say I'm creating web api`

Comment: @Alex asp.net mvc provide you with ability to implement api

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to return either a success or failure result based on whether you encounter an exception?

You may wish to look at the [IExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iexceptionfilter(v=vs.98).aspx) (MVC) or [IExceptionFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.iexceptionfilter(v=vs.118).aspx)  (Http) interface. These filters will listen out for any exceptions, and perform some custom action that you define, for example (MVC example):

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    //perform some custom action, e.g. logging
    _logger.Log(filterContext.Exception);

    //return a particular status
    filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

If you use an exception filter to handle any exceptions that occur, your controllers are free to concentrate on just being controllers:

```
[ResponseType(typeof (List<Report>))]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateReports(IEnumerable<Reports> reports)
{
    var results = SaveReports(reports).ToList();
    return Ok(results);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As i understand you basicly looking for [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

There is a [good article](http://web-matters.blogspot.ru/2014/08/cqrs-with-aspnet-mvc-entity-framework.html) that help you to understand one of the ways how you can implement it. I can't say that it's best practice but you can get some ideas from it.

The main idea is to create `ICommandHandler` and `ICommandDispatcher` interfaces that help you to place basic logic in one place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i wonder for something else. Does it make sense to return such HttpTestResult and if it does why there is no built in feature in MVC?

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy yes it makes sence if you want to handle all your responses same way on client side. MVC provide great `ViewModel` functions i belive that developers don't implement such things from the box becouse it's hard to understand if you beginner and honestly you don't need it in simple applications.